# Using registerNamespaces() in autoload.php

Tags: php, symfony, autoload

I use Symfony and I need to add couple bundles in my autoload.php file, which is in `.../app/` folder. 
So, I basically wrote this:

```
 <?php
// [snip]

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

    $loader->registerNamespaces(array(
        'Behat\BehatBundle' => '/var/www/testsuite.behat/vendor',
        'Behat\Behat'       => '/var/www/testsuite.behat/vendor/Behat/Behat/src',
        'Behat\Gherkin'     => '/var/www/testsuite.behat/vendor/Behat/Gherkin/src',
        'Behat\Mink'        => '/var/www/testsuite.behat/vendor/Behat/Mink/src',
        'Behat\MinkBundle'  => '/var/www/testsuite.behat/vendor',
        'Goutte'            => '/var/www/testsuite.behat/vendor/Goutte/src',
        'Zend'              => '/var/www/testsuite.behat/vendor/Zend/library',
        'Behat\SahiClient'  => '/var/www/testsuite.behat/vendor/Behat/SahiClient/src',
        'Buzz'              => '/var/www/testsuite.behat/vendor/Buzz/lib'
    ));
    $loader->register();
```

And when I run `php app/console` it shows me the error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: loader in /var/www/~/app/autoload.php on line 6
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function registerNamespaces() on a non-object in /var/www/~/app/autoload.php on line 6
```

where "~" is my project's name.

Please, help me with this problem.

Comment: Where do you create the $loader object?

Comment: Consider upgrading to a newer version of Symfony.  registerNamespaces was part of S2.0 and has since been replaced with the composer autoloader.

Comment: @Sven, nowhere. I am actually new at this. So, where should I create this object and how?

Comment: @Cerad, that's bad. Is there any other options?

Comment: So if you are new to this, then your project is also new, and you should really grab the latest version of Symfony instead of that old one. And when it comes to adding/including dependencies, use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org).

Answer (score 2):

Considering you have version 2.1 or higher, this isn't needed anymore. 3th party bundles should be installed via composer, which will take care of the autoloading. This step is only needed for 2.0 versions, as those use the old vendor script created by symfony.

If you, for some reason, still need to register some namespaces, you should do that in your `composer.json` file:

```
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "My\\Namespace": "path/to/me"
        }
    }
}
```

More information: http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0

Comment: I understand, what do you want to say, but in my case - this is useless. Furthemore, I am familiar with Composer. This is about addiing Mink and Behat to my Symphony project.

Comment: 1) why is this useless? 2) if you are familiar to composer, you should know how to install mink and behat using composer and you ahould know that composer handles the autoloading stuff for you

Comment: And where is the problem? `"require": {
        "behat/behat": "2.4.*@stable"
    }` in your composer.json

Comment: @WouterJ Yes, and I've tried, but there were some problems with Mink, so I made it another way and installed Behat + Mink separately from my project. Composer will install Behat and Mink to me again and I just want to make dependencies with already installed version.